# How to format a relationship date?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this request

```
$marche = March::with('attribution')->get()->where('attribution.date_attribution', '2021');
```

how to format 'attribution.date_attribution' to retrieve only the year ?

I tried with Carbon::parse but I got the following error :

```
Could not parse 'attribution.date_attribution': Failed to parse time string (attribution.date_attribution) at position 0 (a): The timezone could not be found in the database
```

Comment: what is current format of attribution.date_attribution?

Comment: it is already formatted in the attribution model: 
`protected $dates = ['deleted_at', 'date_attribution'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but can you try this:

```
$marche = March::
  with('attribution')
->whereHas('attribution', function($query){
    $query->whereYear('date_attribution', '2021');
  })
->get();
```

Comment: That's work pretty good thank you

Answer (score 0):

try with this maybe :

```
->whereYear('attribution.date_attribution', '2021')
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Comment: I got this `BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereYear does not exist.
`

Comment: Before get() function i think